# JTextField and Drawing Images Does Not Work

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtextfield, numberformatexception

So I have the following code, and whenever I press the square tool button it should draw a square where the JTextFields say it should be. But for some reason the JTextField values don't work, and the square cannot be drawn... Here is the square code, and the JTextField:

Initialization of the JTextFields

```
        squareX = new JTextField(3);
        squareY = new JTextField(3);
        squareW = new JTextField(3);
        squareH = new JTextField(3);
```

The ActionListeners:

```
        squareX.addActionListener(listener);
        squareY.addActionListener(listener);
        squareW.addActionListener(listener);
        squareH.addActionListener(listener);
```

This is where I set their values to the text:

```
        x = Integer.parseInt(op.squareX.getText());
        y = Integer.parseInt(op.squareY.getText());
        w = Integer.parseInt(op.squareW.getText());
        h = Integer.parseInt(op.squareH.getText());
        g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
```

And if it matters here is what the error says

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at com.theDevCorner.Game$GridPane.paintComponent(Game.java:155)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1037)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5106)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4890)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:802)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:802)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:745)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:725)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:46)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1684)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor `JTextField(int)` specifys the number of columns rather than the initial value. Therefore the `JTextComponent's` text value is still empty when passed to `Integer#parseInt`. Therefore you can use the constructor that specifys the initial value instead:

```
squareX = new JTextField("3");
squareY = new JTextField("3");
squareW = new JTextField("3");
squareH = new JTextField("3");
```

Comment: Thank you! But I would also like to know if there is a way that I can actually type a value into the text box itself and be able to change it when I press enter. Should I be calling repaint somewhere? @Reimus

Comment: You already have an `ActionListener` which you can use to change the value and also use to call `repaint`

Comment: Altnativly you could use a [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) or [JFormiattedField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) to restrict the user input to numerical values only